# Proving $2x^2-3xy+y^2=0$ is transitive and anti-symmetric or symmetric and reflexive.

Tags: relations

Let $R$ be the binary relation defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $xRy$ iff $2x^2-3xy+y^2=0$

For reflexive we get $2x^2=2x^2\implies-x=x$ which means reflexive on $xRx$

$2x^2-3xy+y^2=0$ tried going for $2y^2-yz+z^2=0$ then adding them together but now I'm stuck with a long useless equation any tips of proving this transitive as for anti symmetric i know $2y^2-3yx+x^2=0$ in case $x=y$ so it should be anti symmetric but I don't know how to say it.

Comment: What is your question? The title mentions transitive and anti/symmetric (whatever that is) but, in the body of your question, you start by mentioning reflexive.

Comment: edited it.wanted to ask about transitive and anti symmetric  then i thought i should see if my reflexive proof is right

Answer (score 1):

Note that\begin{align}x\mathrel Ry&\iff 2x^2-3xy+y^2=0\\&\iff(y-x)(y-2x)=0\\&\iff y=x\vee y=2x.\end{align}So:

- It is not symmetric, since $1\mathrel R2$, but you don't have $2\mathrel R1$.
- It is antisymmetric, since, if $x\neq y$, you cannot have $x\mathrel Ry$ and $y\mathrel Rx$.
- It is not transitive: you have $1\mathrel R2$ and $2\mathrel R4$, but you don't have $1\mathrel R4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $\varphi(x,y)=2x^2-3xy+y^2$. With this notation,
$$ x\mathcal R y\stackrel{\text{def}}{\iff}\varphi(x,y)=0. $$ 
Now the relation $\mathcal R$ is

- reflexive if $\;\varphi(x,x)=0$ for all $x$,
- symmetric if $\;\varphi(x,y)=0\implies\varphi(y,x)=0$ for all $x,y$,
- anti-symmetric if $\;\varphi(x,y)=0$ **and** $\;\varphi(y,x)=0$ imply  $x=y$,
- transitive if, for all $x,y,z$, $\;\varphi(x,y)=0$ **and** $\;\varphi(y,z)=0$ imply $\;\varphi(x,z)=0$.

Can you prove or find counter-examples for any of these?

Comment: i know this is not directly related to the question but can i make x=2 y=1 z=1? or all of them should be different numbers.

Comment: For a counter-example, you can specify any values you please. However, the values you mention do not satisfy the relation.

Comment: i said not directly because i tried on another equation but if i said x=1 y=2 z=2 i can still get (x,z)=0 in this question but if i went z=4 it wont be transitive anymore

Comment: So  you have a counter-example, and transitivity is not satisfied for all $x,y,z$.

Comment: all makes sense now so for an equation such as xy-y2-x+y = 0 if we wanted to get (y,z) into zero z must be 1 or 2 which both will satisfy the equation (x,z) making it transitive?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean exactly. The relation $x\mathcal R y$ is defined by $xy-y^2-x+y=0$?

Comment: yes my bad. it should be transitive because it does not have a counter example right?

Comment: Not  finding a counter-example doesn't prove an assertion is true. However in the  present case, it is indeed transitive. To see it, factorise the polynomial as $(x-y)(y-1)$, so that $x\mathcal R y\iff (x=y)$ **or** $(y=1)$.

Comment: now this got confusing how can i use $x=y$ or $y=1$ to get my answer for sure (sorry for the many replies just that every time i think i got the answer i get faced with another problem )

Comment: You have to examine the different possibilities for $(x,y)$ and for $(y,z)$, combine them in order to deduce each time  one of the possibilities for $(x,z)$ and finally organize the proof to have it as short as possible.

Comment: so for one we take $y=1$ we find x and z possibilities and for other we $x=y$ so we have $y=z$ then $x=z$ which is true so we only have to figure out the first one only?

Comment: Personally, I would start from $z$: if $z=1$ there's nothing to prove. If $z\ne 1$, then $y=z$, so $y\ne 1$ too, &c.

Comment: what do you mean by $z=1$ there is nothing to prove? from what i calculated there is a possibility for $z$ to be 1  so $y$ should also be equal to 1

Comment: By the factorisation, if $z=1$, we have automatically $x\mathcal R z$ (and $y\mathcal R z$).

Answer (score 0):

$\text{R}$ is a binary relation on $\mathbb{R}$ defined as $x\text{R}y\iff 2x^2-3xy+y^2=0$

**Reflexive:**

If $x=y$, then $2x^2-3xy+y^2=2x^2-3x^2+x^2= 0$

Hence, we have $x\text{R}x\ \ \forall \ x \in\mathbb{R}$ and the **relation is Reflexive**

---

Now using a technique called **Completing the Square** we have:

$$\begin{align}x\text{R}y &\iff 2x^2-3xy+y^2=0\\
&\iff x^2-\frac{3}{2}xy+\frac{y^2}{2}=0\\
&\iff x^2-\frac{3}{2}xy+\frac{y^2}{2}+\big(\frac{3y}{4}\big)^2-\big(\frac{3y}{4}\big)^2=0\\
&\iff\big(x-\frac{3y}{4}\big)^2-\big(\frac{y}{4}\big)^2=0\\
&\iff \big(x-\frac{y}{2}\big)\big(x-y\big)=0\\
&\iff x=\frac{y}{2} \ \ \text{Or} \ \ x=y \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ -(1)
\end{align}$$

---

**Antisymmetric:**

We will proceed by contradiction. Let us assume $\text{R}$ is not antisymmetric. Then $\exists \ x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\neq y$ and both $x\text{R}y$, $y\text{R}x$ are satisfied. Since $x\neq y$, by $(1)$ we have the following $$x\text{R}y\Rightarrow x=\frac{y}{2}$$ $$y\text{R}x\Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{2}$$

Thus,

$$x= y=0$$

Which leads to a contradiction. Hence, $\text{R}$ **is antisymmetric**.

---

**Transitive:**

The relation is **not transitive** because $3\text{R}6$ and $6\text{R}12$ but $3\text{R}12$ does not hold.

---

**Symmetric:**

The relation is **not symmetric** because $6\text{R}12$ but $12\text{R}6$ does not hold.